# Line edits at 0 when not used? PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

i'm in a situation where i take the user input and do some math operations.. The user selects an item from a combobox, and inputs a number in the line edit next to it. When he clicks ok, it returns (comboboxselectedvalue)+(lineeditvalue), it works, most of the time, my problem is, when the user leaves the lineedit in blank, it returns an error:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

```
cb1 = self.lineEdit.text()
zb1=self.comboBox.currentText()
az1 = int(cb1)
print(zb1+az1)
```

How can i set the value of line edits to 0 when nothing is typed in and left in blank? I have 20 line edits and 20 combo boxes..

Comment: `if cb1 == "":` would probably be a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is going to raise an exception whenever the user enters anything that's not a number—including nothing at all.

The nicest way to handle this is by validating the entry (and pre-filling it with something valid, like `0`), so they can't click OK with something invalid in the box.

But if you want to handle this in the "engine" code instead of in the GUI, you can; it just won't be as nice a user experience.

It sounds like what you want to do is treat an empty box as `0`. What about a non-empty but non-numeric entry? Should that also be treated as `0`? If so, this is easy; the exception already catches exactly what you want to catch, so you just need to handle it.

```
try:
    az1 = int(cb1)
except ValueError:
    az1 = 0
```

If, on the other hand, you want to treat non-numeric entries different from empty, it's a bit more complicated; the exception lumps them both in together, so you'd need an `if` test either instead of or in addition to the exception. If, say, you wanted non-numeric text to abort the program as it currently does, but an empty box to mean 0, you could write:

```
try:
    az1 = int(cb1)
except ValueError:
    if not az1:
        az1 = 0
    else:
        raise
```

Or, more briefly:

```
az1 = int(cb1) if cb1 else 0
```